# Angular $q with two "then": will second then be called if first reaches error handler?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

```
$q.all([firstPromise, secondPromise])
    .then(successHandler1, errorHandler1)
    .then(successHandler2, errorHandler2);
```

Will successHandler2 be called after errorHandler1 is called ?

Comment: @TirthrajBarot should be an answer

Comment: I have put it in answer. @SergeyPanfilov

Comment: It depends on your errorHandler1: if it throws an error or returns a rejected promise, then errorHandler2 will be called. Otherwise, successHandler2 will be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of calls is this:

successHandler1 then successHandler2
OR
errorHandler1 the errorHandler2

Answer (score 1):

if the value returns from reject callback, then success callback will be executed, if an error throwed, then the error callback will be executed.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myController', function ($q) {
  $q(function (resolve, reject) {
    reject('1');
  })
  .then(
    function(resolve) {
      console.log('resolve 1');
      return 'resolve 1';
    },
    function(reject) {
      console.log('reject 1');
      throw 'reject 1'
    })
  .then(
    function(resolve) {
      console.log('resolve 2');
    },
    function(reject) {
      console.log('reject 2');
      return 'reject 2'
    })
  .then(
    function(resolve) {
      console.log('resolve 3');

    },
    function(reject) {
      console.log('reject 3');
    })
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/k2UprgZd0J4RP8PtDye2?p=preview

console:

reject 1

reject 2

resolve 3